# The norm of a continuous vector valued function is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I need to know if the norm of a continuous vector valued function is continuous. Suppose $f=(f_1,...,f_n)$ is a vector valued continuous function on $[a,b]$. Can we say that $||f(x)||$ is continuous on $[a,b]$? Would appreciate any assistance. Thank you.

Comment: The norm is continuous, and compositions of continuous functions are continuous, so yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** the composition of two continuous functions is continuous, so it is sufficient to show that the norm function $\|\cdot \|:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous

---

Clarification: $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$.  We can then write $\|f(x)\|$ as $\|\cdot\|\circ f : [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$.  Because $f$ is continuous and $\|\cdot\|$ is continuous, the composition $\|\cdot\|\circ f$ must also be continuous.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more if possible. How can the composition of the functions being continuous lead to the norm being continuous?

Comment: @RajindaWickrama: It doesn't, they're two separate facts.  But combined they give the desired conclusion.

Comment: @RajindaWickrama I've updated my answer a bit, see if that makes more sense to you

Comment: @Omnomnomnom now it makes sense! thanks!